# Foundation button dropdown - reverse arrow on click

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I'm using the button dropdown in Foundation (http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown_buttons.html), is there a way to change the down arrow on click to an up arrow when the menu is open? Then back to an down arrow on close?

```
<button href="#" data-dropdown="drop1" aria-controls="drop1" aria-expanded="false" class="button dropdown">Dropdown Button</button><br>
<ul id="drop1" data-dropdown-content class="f-dropdown" aria-hidden="true">
  <li><a href="#">This is a link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">This is another</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Yet another</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this rule somewhere into your CSS:

```
.dropdown[aria-expanded="true"]::after {
   border-color: transparent transparent white;
   top: 40%;
}
```

Then it should work like you need.

[CodePen example](http://codepen.io/Akarienta/pen/xwLJvQ)